# Is it possible to set a symbolic breakpoint within a block?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is my stack trace:

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x39bdcb36 objc_msgSend + 22
1     Foundation                            0x301423a3 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 55
2     Foundation                            0x301467cf -[NSBlockOperation main] + 131
3     Foundation                            0x3013697b -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 771
4     Foundation                            0x301dab35 __NSOQSchedule_f + 61
5     libdispatch.dylib                     0x3a0ca6df _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 111
6     libdispatch.dylib                     0x3a0cbda5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 221
7     libdispatch.dylib                     0x3a0cbf8d _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 57
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x3a206dbf _pthread_wqthread + 299
```

What I'd like to do is set a breakpoint at

```
__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke
```

and inspect the registers to see what it is supposed to be accessing. Setting

```
__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke
```

as the breakpoint does not trigger anything. Setting a breakpoint at

```
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]
```

works, but I still don't know what is happening inside that block. I appreciate any suggestions.

**Update**
I was able to come up with a workaround that I've added as an answer. The source of the crash is likely to be that my NSURLConnectionDelegate (a class named WebOperation in this case) is being deallocated somewhere, however I am having a very difficult time replicating it. If there are any insights to be gained I'll add them here.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the block (i.e. is the block yours)?

Comment: No, the block is part of Foundation, so I don't have the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to set the breakpoint directly using "Add Exception Breakpoint..." However what I was able to do was set a breakpoint in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)con didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

When I hit the breakpoint it looked like this:

```
#0  0x00063e2c in -[WebOperation connection:didReceiveData:] at /Users/.../WebOperation.mm:638
#1  0x31c9b3a2 in __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke ()
#2  0x31c9b2e6 in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] ()
#3  0x31c9b200 in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] ()
#4  0x31c9b550 in _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData ()
#5  0x30fce274 in ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic29_delegate_didReceiveDataArrayEv_block_invoke ()
#6  0x30fcdae2 in ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 ()
#7  0x30fff31e in ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#8  0x31295718 in CFArrayApplyFunction ()
#9  0x30f65c3c in RunloopBlockContext::perform() ()
#10 0x30f65b0c in MultiplexerSource::perform() ()
#11 0x30f659a0 in MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) ()
#12 0x3132d18a in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x3132c65a in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#14 0x3132ae4e in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x31295ce6 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x31295aca in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x35f7f282 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x33b37a40 in UIApplicationMain ()
#19 0x00020c6e in main at /Users/.../main.mm:16
```

As you can see the stacktrace, the target block is the direct caller of connection:didReceiveData: By clicking on that step of the stack trace, you can actually set a breakpoint there. I added an action to the breakpoint "register read" and this is what I got in the debugger:

```
General Purpose Registers:
        r0 = 0x27d96afc
        r1 = 0x3da33230  libsystem_pthread.dylib`_MergedGlobals11 + 224
        r2 = 0x00004000
        r3 = 0x27d967e0
        r4 = 0x27d96994
        r5 = 0x27d96998
        r6 = 0x188d2a00
        r7 = 0x27d96970
        r8 = 0x17596310
        r9 = 0x1775eb78
       r10 = 0x27d969d4
       r11 = 0x00000000
       r12 = 0x00870b28  (void *)0x3bc3dc19: _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister + 1
        sp = 0x27d96968
        lr = 0x000b51d9  SomeProject`-[WebOperation connection:didFailWithError:] + 733 at WebOperation.mm:652
        pc = 0x31c9b3a2  Foundation`__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 54
      cpsr = 0x60000030
```

Register lr points to the delegate method being invoked, so I now have consistent information on what is being called from this block.